# Trouble in Proving the Sequential Criterion for Limits at Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $A\subseteq R,$ let $f : A\to R,$ and suppose that $(a,\infty)\subseteq A$ for some $a \in R.$ Then the following statements are equivalent:

(i) $L=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$

(ii) For every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A \cap (a,\infty)=(a,\infty)$ such that $\lim x_n=\infty$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L.$

I tried proving this in the following way:

First we try to show, $(i)\implies (ii).$ If, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ then this means,

For every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $K>a$ such that if $x\geq K,$ we have $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon.$

Now, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $A \cap (a,\infty)=(a,\infty)$ such that $\lim x_n=\infty$ then, $\exists M\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\gt K(\gt a),$  when $n\geq M.$ But if, $x_n>K$ we have, $|f(x_n)-L|\lt \epsilon.$ To sum, we have shown that, if $n\geq M$, then, $|f(x_n)-L|\lt \epsilon.$ But $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $(x_n)$ was arbitrary and this implies, that for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A \cap (a,\infty)=(a,\infty)$ such that $\lim x_n=\infty$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L.$

---

*However, while to show the converse, I think I make my argument faulty:*

Next, we try to show, that $(ii)\implies (i).$

If for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A \cap (a,\infty)=(a,\infty)$ such that $\lim x_n=\infty$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L,$ then we fix,  an arbitrary $\epsilon\gt 0.$

Now, we denote, each sequence as $X_i=(x_n^{(i)})$, where $i\in \Bbb N$ and $X_i\in A \cap (a,\infty)=(a,\infty)$. If $\lim X_i=\infty$ for a particular $i\in Bbb N$ then $\exists M_i\in \Bbb N$ such that, $|f(x_n^{(i)}-L|\lt \epsilon$ for all $n\geq M.$ For each, $X_i$ we obtain, an $M_i$ and if, $M=\max(M_i)_{i\in \Bbb N},$ we may take, $x\geq M$ and then, $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon.$ Hence, we claim that, $L=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x).$

---

I doubt my proof about the converse statement as, $\max\{\text{infinite set}\}$ has no meaning at all. We can take $\max$ element in a finite set and not in an infinite one. Secondly, in the part, where I wrote, "$x\geq M$ and then, $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$" might be faulty as well. This is because, if $x\geq M$  then, $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$ will be true, only if, $x$ is in some properly diverging sequence $X_i$ tending to $\infty.$ But, how can we gurantee, that $x$ will be in such a sequence $X_i$ just like that?

For these two reasons, I feel my argument breaks down.

All in all, I don't understand how to show, $(ii)\implies (i)$ ?

Comment: For $(ii) \implies (i)$, try the contrapositive.

Comment: @terran Contrapositive of what ? $(i)\to (ii)$ ?

Comment: No. Instead of proving that $(i)\implies(ii)$, prove that, if $(ii)$ is false, then $(i)$ is false too.

Comment: The contrapositive of $(ii) \implies (i)$ is $\text{not } (i) \implies \text{not } (ii)$.

Comment: I agree with the contrapositive idea, i.e. show that if $(i)$ isn't true, then $(ii)$ also isn't true. As for why your other idea doesn't quite work, you've assumed that you can assign every subsequence an integer, but it turns out the set of sequences of integers is uncountably infinite, so that's not possible. That's not really a problem, since you can still define the set of $M$'s such that a subsequence gets you in $\epsilon$ range of the limit. Taking the max of an infinite set isn't nonsensical either (it's usually called the supremum), the problem is that this supremum may be infinite.

Comment: @terran If I follow your idea, then I have to prove : If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\neq L$ then, $\exists$  $(x_n)\in A\cap (0,\infty)$ such that $\lim x_n=\infty$ but, $\lim f(x_n)\neq L.$ But then, how to prove this?

Comment: K. Jiang has provided a proof in their answer.

Comment: @terran I have answered this question as well. Can you validate whether you meant that or not? Here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4758922/1180560 . Or if you want, you might scroll diwn :)

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I meant! :-)

Comment: @terran Thanks a ton for confirming !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove that $(ii)\implies (i)$ in a much simpler way. We show this,  by proving that the contrapositive of the statement i.e $\neg (i)\implies \neg (ii)$ is true.

The contrapositive translates to the below statement:

*If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq L$ then $\exists (x_n)\in A\cap (a,\infty)$ satisfying, $\lim x_n=\infty$ such that, $\lim f(x_n)\neq L\tag 1$*

This is true, for if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq L$ then, $\exists \epsilon\gt 0$ such that, $\forall K_i\gt a$  $\exists x'_i\gt K_i$ we have, $|f(x'_i)-L|\geq \epsilon.$ We consider the sequence $(x_i')\in A\cap (a,\infty)$ and note that, $\lim x_i' =\infty.$

This can readily be verified if, $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ then, $\exists K_{i_0}\in\Bbb N$ such that $K_{i_0}\gt \alpha$ then, $x'_{i_0}>K_{i_0}>\alpha$ and hence, $\forall i\geq i_0$ we have, $x'_i\gt K_i\gt K_{i_0}\gt\alpha$ so that $x'_i\gt \alpha$ for all $i\geq i_0.$ Hence, $\lim x'_i=\infty$ follows.

But we note that, $|f(x'_i)-L|\geq \epsilon$ for all $i\in \Bbb N.$ So, the required sequence in $(1)$ is $(x_i').$ So, $(1)$ is indeed true and so, $(ii)\implies (i).$

The portion, $(i)\implies (ii)$ in OP seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted in the comments, you can show that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f (x) \ne L$, then there is some sequence $(x_n)$ (where $x_n > a$ for each $n$) with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$ such that $(f (x_n))$ does not converge to $L$.

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f (x) \ne L$, then there is some open ball $C = B (L, \varepsilon)$ such that $f^{-1} (C)$ does not contain any set of the form $A \cap (r, \infty)$, where $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $(2 |a|, \infty) \subseteq (a, \infty) \subseteq A$, this implies there is some element $x_1 > 2 |a| \ge 0$ of $A$ such that $f (x_1) \notin C$. Now, since $(2 x_1, \infty) \subseteq (a, \infty) \subseteq A$, there is some $x_2 > 2 x_1$ contained in $A$ such that $f (x_2) \notin C$. Continue inductively so that we get a sequence of points of $A$

$$x_1 < x_2 < \dots$$

each of which is positive and none of whose images is contained in $C$. We claim that this sequence satisfies the desired properties.

It is easy to see that $(f (x_n))$ does not converge to $L$, since the neighborhood $C$ of $L$ contains no points of this sequence (by design).

To show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$, assume for the sake of contradiction that $x_n < s$ for each $n$ for some $s \in A$. Note that $s$ must be positive since each $x_n$ is positive. By design, $x_{n + 1} > 2 x_n$ for each $n$, so that $x_n > x_1 (2)^{n - 1}$. So, we have that $2^{n - 1} < \frac{x_n}{x_1} < \frac{s}{x_1} \implies n < 1 + \log_2 \left( \frac{s}{x_1} \right)$ for each positive integer $n$, clearly a contradiction.